# Selenium Webdriver - errors

Tags: java, selenium

I am learning test automation and wrote a script in Selenium Webdriver, however I got a lot of errors below.
I did the installation with tutorials and followed all the steps, however something is not working. 
The errors don't tell me much information so could anyone have a look at it and tell me what should I do in this case?
Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    String baseUrl = "http://www.facebook.com";
    String tagName = "";

    driver.get(baseUrl);
    tagName = driver.findElement(By.id("email")).getTagName();
    System.out.println(tagName);
    driver.close();
    System.exit(0);
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-5N6LIMJ', ip: '192.168.0.16', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.waitUntilAvailable(XpiDriverService.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.start(XpiDriverService.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at newpackage.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:12)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:5176/hub/status] to be available after 45010 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.waitUntilAvailable(XpiDriverService.java:245)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Use `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/) library instead of setup the driver binary manually.

> WebDriverManager allows to automate the management of the binary
>   drivers (e.g. chromedriver, geckodriver, etc.) required by Selenium
>   WebDriver.

Firstly add it to your project, e.g.

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>        
    </dependency>
```

Then replace `System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\geckodriver.exe");` with `WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();` and *WebDriverManager* will do all the magic for you:

> 1. It checks the version of the browser installed in your machine (e.g. Chrome, Firefox).
> 2. It checks the version of the driver (e.g. chromedriver, geckodriver). If unknown, it uses the latest version of the driver.
> 3. It downloads the WebDriver binary if it is not present on the WebDriverManager cache (~/.m2/repository/webdriver by default).
> 4. It exports the proper WebDriver Java environment variables required by Selenium (not done when using WebDriverManager from the
>      CLI or as a Server).
>
> WebDriverManager resolves the driver binaries for the browsers Chrome,
>   Firefox, Opera, PhantomJS, Microsoft Edge, and Internet Explorer. For
>   that, it provides several drivers managers for these browsers. These
>   drivers managers can be used as follows:

```java
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
    WebDriverManager.operadriver().setup();
    WebDriverManager.phantomjs().setup();
    WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
    WebDriverManager.iedriver().setup();
```

You should use either *Maven* or *Gradle* to build your application, check this post: [Basic example program using WebDriver Java Maven](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/maven-tutorials/simple-example-program-using-webdriver-maven-java)

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your help. A lot of error already disappeared except one. Do you know how to resolve that? exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 WebDriverManager cannot be resolved

 at newpackage.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:20)

Comment: What tools are you using to build a run your application ?

Comment: Eclipse IDE 2019‑09

Comment: Did you import `WebDriverManager.class` in the class with the main method ?

Comment: I advice you to use maven or gradle to build your java applications. I added a link in my answer in where you can learn how to use selenium with eclipse and maven

Comment: Thank you ery much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

User this Code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to add this : 
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
            "C:\\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); 
    options.setCapability("marionette", false);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to keep it simple if you are new to automation. Do not use WebDriver Manager instead just correctly set the System property as suggested by people above.

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\geckodriver.exe");

Only this should resolve the issue.But still if you face any exception then please share it here. Since you are new so proceed slowly by understanding everything. Do not make the change if you do not understand the purpose of it.